# 500 error on javascript, ajax update of MYSQL cell

Tags: javascript, php

jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4

POST https://xyz/update.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

send    @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4

ajax    @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
myFunction  @   6011c7fbf.min.js?ver=1600216310:3
onclick @   (index):453

I am getting a 500 error above from the console. What I dont know is whether the error is in my PHP in trying to update the row or elsewhere.

**PHP** below is contained inside my update-file.php file

```
function function_1() {
    global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'my_table_name' SET `currentstatus` = 'myupdate1' WHERE ID = '1'"));   

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT** contained on the page

```
function myFunction() {

      jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/yummy/update-file.php',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
  alert("I've been clicked!!");
}
```

**HTML**

Go!

**EDIT 1**

As per suggestions I have updated as such:

**JAVASCIPT**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    action: 'function_1',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

Thinking the above was not correct I also tried :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.https://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/yummy/update-waitinglist.php, // this is the location of the update php below
    action: 'function_1',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

**PHP** below is contained inside my update-file.php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_function_1', 'myfunctionname'); // logged in user can make a call
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_function_1', 'myfunctionname'); // non logged in user can make a call

function myfunctionname() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'my_table_name' SET `currentstatus` = 'myupdate1' WHERE ID = '1'"));
    die($results);

}
```

ADDED TO FUNCTIONS FILE
wp_localize_script('myfunctionname', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

With the EDIT 1 in place, I also get an error - Notice: wp_localize_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the wait list_update handle. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. [www.xyz.com/wp-includes/functions.php](http://www.xyz.com/wp-includes/functions.php) on line 5225 . I must have misunderstood something in the suggestion.

**EDIT 2** Got everything else working but the button doesnt seem to update anything.

PHP from functions file -

```
function my_scripts() {   
wp_enqueue_script( 'waitlist_update_call', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/waitlist_update_call.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
wp_localize_script('waitlist_update_call', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    echo getcwd();
//calls Waitinglist data and creates table
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');

add_action('wp_ajax_waitlist_update_function', 'waitlist_update_function'); // logged in user can make a call

function waitlist_update_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'mytablename' SET `currentstatus` = 
    'myupdate1' WHERE ID = '1'"));
    die($results);

}
```

JS

```
// JavaScript Document
function update() {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    // add your action inside data object
    data: { 
      action: 'waitlist_update_function' 
    },
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
}
```

HTML
Go!

Comment: the issue is on the server as a 500 response means the server side failed - check server (php) logs for errors

Comment: Thanks. So the PHP string I have is no good then is the theory?

Comment: I can see you are using wordpress. You are calling a file from your theme folder - well this is **odd** and not how this should be done. Please add what you are trying to do with this code

Comment: also how you and from where this click function is being called ?

Comment: Should use the [WP AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) , not a good idea sending directly to theme path. Did you load wp in that file before using  `$wpdb`?

Comment: No idea ... the PHP is where the error is

Comment: The issue is with url, it needs to be absolute.

Comment: @charlietfl  When you ask if I loaded WP, I Am not sure what you mean? The $WPDB is contaned in a custom shortcodes file and in inside the update-waitlist.php file only

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  the click is being called when a user clicks the button in the HTML. Does that help?

Comment: @theodore where is this `function_1`  being called in PHP. calling a file via ajax does not mean a php function will be executed itself.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  I thought it was being called in my original script in the JS..Sorry I do see that wasnt clear. I updated the above example and the EDIT 1 to tell you more

Comment: Check your server error logs to see what exact reason is for the 500 error

Comment: @charlietfl I must admit I am uncertain how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be with the URL, it must be absolute I think.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    //....
    url: 'http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/themes/yummy/update-waitlist.php'
    // ...
```

**The WordPress way**

> You must enqueue your JS file **script.js** before with same `handle`
> and then localize after it

Localize the script to pass generic data. We will pass the `ajax_url` with `my_ajax` object.

**functions.php**

```php
wp_localize_script('your-script-handle', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Then in your script file, you can use the `my_ajax` object to get the AJAX URL. Define a action `function_1` which will be executed when this AJAX call is requested.

**script.js**

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'function_1',
    }
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

Define a function and attach it with Ajax action that will query the database & returns the result.

**functions.php**

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_function_1', 'function_to_execute_some_query'); // logged in user can make a call
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_function_1', 'function_to_execute_some_query'); // non logged in user can make a call

function function_to_execute_some_query() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'wp_wpdatatable_4' SET `currentstatus` = 
    'myupdate1' WHERE wdt_ID = '1'"));
    die($results);

}
```

Comment: thanks so much for this detailed answer. I must be misinterpreting something because having followed the instructions above ( I think) I am getting a  Uncaught ReferenceError: my_ajax is not defined on page load and a Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: also added above an additional error about scripts.

Comment: @theodore In your updated script, remove the `my_ajax.` and include the whole path of the file only inside single quotes. As I said in above answer, to use the generic data we need to localize it for the specific script & without localization it will not work. So, remove `my_ajax` and include the absolute path only. See the first part of my answer.

Either follow the first answer or update everything with the answer below The WordPress way.

Comment: Ah thanks. I will try and report back. I had taken it literally since someone above said dont use the whole file path. Confirming it would look like url: https://maydomain.com/path instead of my_ajax.ajax_url

Comment: Yes, it would look like the the URL you have mentioned & also you shouldn't use the whole path. You should follow the WordPress way which is recommended.

Comment: Wait sorry now I am confused again. Do I use the whole path or no? I am using the wordpress method you so kindly wrote out

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :D , using the whole path without localizing is not recommended. So, follow the WordPress way, it should be all good.

Comment: Still think I am missing something. To keep this cleaner, I started a new question for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63930544/wp-enqueue-script-order-and-localize-errors-hook-needed

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Dont suppose you could direct me on using the onclick to call the ajax command? I think I have it right since I am not getting errors but it is not actually doing anything either. I click and nothing happens. No errors

Comment: You have to wrap the Ajax code inside a function and attach the function with button's click event.