# Directory structure issue when calling a JS file and Ajax

Tags: php, html, directory, subdirectory

I can not seem to make the call to the proper JS file location despite trying everything that I can think of. Below is the way that it should be from everything I know to find that "myjsfile.js" (name replaced for stackoverflow)

```
function my_scripts() {   
 wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/myjsfile.js' ), array('jquery'), null, true );
 wp_localize_script('myscript', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

My file I am trying to call is located in:

`https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js`

The above PHP script is located in:

`https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"`

I have tried:

```
'/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'../assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'../../assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'../themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'../../themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
'../wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'
https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js
```

all with no luck. By default `'/assets/js/myjsfile.js'` doesn't call the JS file but instead calls `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. The other examples above all call some version of `https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js` and simply add to the proper directory structure whatever I have placed in front of the `/assets/js/myjsfile.js`. It doubles it. Can anyone point out where I seem to be going wrong here?

**EDIT 1**
I have also tried:

```
function my_scripts() {   
 wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', ( get_theme_file_uri() ).'/assets/js/myjsfile.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
 wp_localize_script('myscript', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

```
echo getcwd(); shows me in the public directory /home/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding Ajax code here as well as PHP directory ECHO attempts and their results
AJAX
File named - `"myjsfile.js"`

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    action: 'waitlist_update',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

PHP echo directory attempts:
`$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; echo $path;` shows - /home/food/domains/mysite.com/private_html
`but echo getcwd();` shows /home/food/domains/mysite.com/public_html

**EDIT 3**
Updated AJAX and add full code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajax_url,
    // add your action inside data object
    data: { 
      action: 'waitlist_update' 
    },
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

PHP code

```
   function my_scripts() {   


 wp_enqueue_script( 'waitlist_update_call', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/waitlist_update_call.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_localize_script('waitlist_update_call', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    //calls Waitinglist data and creates table
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
    
    add_action('wp_ajax_waitlist_update', 'waitlist_update'); // logged in user can make a call
    
    function waitlist_update() {
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'my_table' SET `currentstatus` = 
        'myupdate1' WHERE wdt_ID = '1'"));
        die($results);
    
    }
```

**HTML**
Go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check my old answers, I have already fixed this issue for you as well.

**Proper way:**

`wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/myjsfile.js', array('jquery'), false, true);`

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the correct URI of the active theme so that it will point to the root of your theme.

`https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme`

If you are using a **child theme**, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

**Update:**

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    // add your action inside data object
    data: { 
      action: 'waitlist_update' 
    },
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_waitlist_update', 'update_function');
    
function update_function() {
  global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE 'my_table' SET `currentstatus` = 'myupdate1' WHERE wdt_ID = '1'"));
  die($results);
}
```

`wp_ajax_waitlist_update` the `waitlist_update` is the action that ajax will trigger from your JavaScript. `update_function` is the function that will be called after the Ajax is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just specify the full path to the file in the head of your html document, example;

```
 https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js
```

Or in PHP set a path equal to the document root of your site plus folders that point to the final location of the file;

```
 // Check the correct folder your script is located in
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/";
```

Now include your js file in the HTML

```
 <script src='<?php $path."myjsfile.js"; ?>'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that too to set the full path. It doubles it  -https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/ https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/"mytheme"/assets/js/myjsfile.js'. Where would I set the $path? Inside the function? If I put it inside the function it gives me an invalid T-String error.

Comment: In that case I would echo out $path without any extra folders added (just the document root) and see what it produces then you should know where you are.

Comment: Outside of any existing code like this: $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; echo $path;

Comment: Comment out or remove the faulty code then check the path.

Comment: $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; echo $path; shows - /home/food/domains/mysite.com/private_html but echo getcwd(); shows /home/food/domains/mysite.com/public_html

Comment: I can't really help with WordPress as I don't use it but it looks like something else is controlling access to directories. I'd check the .htaccess file.